# Gradle include Freemarker files from webapp directory

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, jar, freemarker

I have a spring boot project that gets turned into jar through gradle.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.23'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.1.4.Final'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.5.1'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    baseName = 'carefree-cooking'
    version = '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'carefree.cooking.Application'
    }
}

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

In my `@Configuration` I have Freemarker configured the following way

```
@Bean(name = "freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig()
{
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/");
    return configurer;
}

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/template/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

My controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController
{
    @RequestMapping()
    public String index(ModelMap model)
    {
        return "page";
    }
}
```

And my `page.ftl` is located in

`src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\template\page.ftl`

And just says Hello world.

Whenever I build my jar by running
`./gradlew clean jar`
I notice that in created jar `page.ftl` does not exist

When I run my spring boot application it can not find `page.ftl`, however if I create a directory
`webapp\WEB-INF\template\page.ftl`
where jar is located then the `page.ftl` is found.

How do I configure `gradle` to include `page.ftl` and configure my `@Configuration` class to look there for `page.ftl`?

I have tried adding

```
from("${projectDir}/src/main") {
    include('webapp/WEB-INF/**')
}
```

To my jar task in build.gradle, and although this ensures that `page.ftl` is included in the jar, my application still can not find it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `src/main/webapp` are only included in the built archive when it's a war file. They are not included when building a jar. You have already applied the war plugin so `./gradlew clean war` should work. If you want a fat war, i.e one that can be run with `java -jar`, then run `./gradlew clean bootRepackage`.